# Connecting C++ backend to Javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, google-maps, backend

I was hoping to make a website that displays a google map with points based of information returned by a C++ function.  I know you can use Java Server Pages to call java methods on the server with javascript.  Would there be a way to connect C++ code on the server with javascript in order to produce the same result as java server pages?

Answer (score 3):

Since JavaScript runs at a completely different environment which is separated from the webserver by a HTTP connection, your best bet is to fire a HTTP request to the server side on a specific URL which has the particular C++ code attached.

You can fire asynchronous HTTP requests in JavaScript using [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest), the core technique behind ["Ajax"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). The w3schools provides a concise [introduction](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) to Ajax. To make it all less verbose and bloated, you may consider to grab the [jQuery](http://jquery.com) library which has under each an [`$.ajax`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax) function for this purpose.

---

That said, [Java Server Pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) is absolutely not to be compared with [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript). JSP is a Java based server side view technology which provides a template to write HTML/CSS/JS in and offers capabilities to control the page flow dynamically and interact with backend Java code using taglibs and expression language. It runs all on the server machine, produces a HTML page and sends it over HTTP to the client side. The C++/C#/NET counterpart of JSP is [ASP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages).